# Is it possible to know maximum CPU speed in MHZ in java?

Tags: java, runtime, cpu, processor

Is it possible to know maximum CPU speed in MHZ in java programatically?

After a huge search in google and here i did not find the way to get it.

I found a way to do it which works in Android but I'm not developing this for android, so it does not work. (https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/19810/how-can-i-determine-max-cpu-speed-at-runtime/59351)

I need it to work in a linux/osx/windows machine.

Comment: The major issue is not the OS, it is the architecture. Java potentially targets every existing architecture, can you restrict the list? Say, x86(-64) only? ARM?

Comment: @MargaretBloom yes, ofcourse, will be x86 machines with 64 bit's processors

Comment: In linux, read the file /proc/cpuinfo.

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no standard API in the JVM that reveals this information. You can create JNI for each platform that calls appropriate native OS methods to learn this information, but nothing is part of the standard, 100%-java, API.

Comment: and which whould be that native methods for Linux, WIndows an OS X ? can't find them

Comment: Read and parse /proc/cpuinfo.  Each available processor will have an entry.

Comment: @NullPointerException: parsing `/proc/cpuinfo` works on Linux.  Another answer mentions a perl module(!) to get info on Windows.  I don't know about macOS.

Answer (score -1):

On windows, you should be able to get the info from Win32 SystemInfo
http://search.cpan.org/~cjohnston/Win32-SystemInfo-0.12/SystemInfo.pm

Comment: the question is about Java, and Linux/macOS/Windows, not just Win32.

Comment: Indeed. If you want to run on three different operating systems, you will need at least three different ways to detemine the required result.  I suppose the downvoter could complain you only gave one-third of the answer :)

Comment: @ChristophBimminger: Perhaps because this is a Java question and you linked docs for a perl module which don't directly help in reimplementing it in Java, like which Win32 APIs to use.  Unless "SystemInfo" is also the name of the right Win32 API to look for, this is barely a link-only answer, and link-only answers are frowned upon on Stack Overflow.  (Due to the possibility of link rot among other things.)